# highchart giving no output

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi i am following standard tutorial on highcharts site .http://docs.highcharts.com/#your-first-chart
i have followed same instruction, and wrote this code. i am not getting any output on screen. please check, what wrong i have done.

## initially i tried to load j-query from net, it didnt worked, now i have downloaded it locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="/home/bhavuk/Documents/code/django/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="/home/bhavuk/Documents/code/django/Highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>
<title> high charts </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<p> hey i am learning high charts</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors? Add $(document).ready();

Answer (score 2):

In the example on highcharts there is a class defined in the div, while in the code there is an id referenced.
Changing #container to .container fixed it.

The firefox error console showed a #13 error which gave the clue to the mystery.

BTW, had to load jquery and highcharts before the highchart example script.

Answer (score 0):

May be something is messing with jquery standard variable. Try to add `$ = jQuery.noConflict()` in the beginning of the script. And give more specific information, like; browser, jsfiddle, error if any